# Upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10, update-manager crashed, and now hangs

Tags: 13.04, update-manager

I started `update-manager` in order to do the 13.04 to 13.10 upgrade. At some point not far into the process, it died with some sort of unexplained error. (There was a message in the console about a Unicode decode failure, but I don't know whether to pay attention to that; Linux GUI programs spew out continual errors and warnings under apparently normal operation.)

When I start it back up now, it just sits there burning CPU, showing the initial "Checking for updates" progress screen. The "Stop" button is greyed-out.

I *think* that before the thing died the first time, it had gotten part-way, or maybe all the way, through the process of updating my apt files to point to the new release.

At this point, should I just kill the `update-manager` process and do a manual `apt-get dist-upgrade` from the command line? Is there something I should check first to make sure that won't be a disaster?

Comment: If your system still gets trashed you could try to boot 14.04 daily image and use its installer to upgrade to 14.04 so that no user files are deleted. It worked for me when my 13.10 became unbootable during upgrade.

Comment: @user205301 well that's somewhat problematic as I've got everything installed on an encrypted LVM partition (it's a work laptop). Installing onto an existing encrypted partition is a giant pain in the neck, unless 14.04 has fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're going to want to do the dist-upgrade command from Terminal. First, you should run auto-remove, just to make sure all goes smoothly.

Comment: OK but what exactly do you mean by "auto-remove"? Do you mean `apt-get auto-clean`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have explained that. There's a command that will remove stray packages like ones from unfinished install processes and so-on. Just type 'sudo apt-get autoremove'

Comment: He wants to upgrade to Saucy, which is not done by `apt-get dist-upgrade`, but with `do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @the_Seppi the problem is that `do-release-upgrade` **crashes** with a Python exception.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ubuntu+upgrade+unicode+decode+failure

Comment: @the_Seppi well gee thanks but the solution given in the other AskUbuntu question on the topic doesn't work. I'm now seeing exactly the same problem on a different machine. The `update-manager` gets to a  point at which it simply will not start at all.

Comment: ... which appears to be [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/628657)